# How do I add headers to files downloaded from ServiceStack's Virtual File System?

Tags: http, servicestack, cache-control

I am leveraging `ServiceStack`'s Virtual File System and the [code-snippet on the wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Virtual-file-system#registering-additional-virtual-path-providers) to minify content at startup-time.  However, I don't see a way that I can add in custom headers, like [those recommended](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching#cache-control) for `Cache-Control`, etc.

I could possibly use Global Response Filters, but a) I don't think they play with "static" files, and b) that require some gnarly response logic.

How can I add headers to content served by a `IVirtualPathProvider` in ServiceStack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static files are served by the [StaticFileHandler](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Host/Handlers/StaticFileHandler.cs). It already adds [Cache-Control and LastModified headers](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/862e2fae07a74298665e4ba804738bbf2337e2ae/src/ServiceStack/Host/Handlers/StaticFileHandler.cs#L140-L155) and will [return a 304](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/862e2fae07a74298665e4ba804738bbf2337e2ae/src/ServiceStack/Host/Handlers/StaticFileHandler.cs#L148) if the file hasn't been modified since it was last requested.

The latest version of `InMemoryVirtualPathProvider` has been [rewritten](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/5e9594d9edae10efb8683c69199c705e99d6eccd) to maintain [consistent behavior with the new S3VirtualPathProvider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Aws/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Aws.Tests/S3/VirtualPathProviderTests.cs) which now includes the LastModified timestamp for each file which the `StaticFileHandler` can take advantage of.

This change is available from v4.0.47 that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

### Adding headers with a Custom StaticFilesHandler ResponseFilter

You can still add your own custom HTTP Response headers by registering a `StaticFileHandler.ResponseFilter`, e.g:

```
StaticFileHandler.ResponseFilter = (req,res,file) => {
    res.AddHeader(headerName, headerValue);

    //res.Close(); Closing the Response will stop further processing
};
```

Comment: Ask and ye shall receive.  Good to know the StaticFileHandler already adds cache-control.  I browse with Chrome debug tools up to check headers, and blitzed that it requests Cache-Control: no-cache.